# Is there a standard name for the date format dd-MMM-yyyy? For example 01-Oct-2013

Tags: date, datetime, mask, datetime-format

I made a Java enum of standard date and time formats but I want the names to be the format mask where possible or the name of the standard.  Since dd-MMM-yyyy is not a valid variable name, I'd like to name it the standard.  For example, I have an entry called ISO8601 for yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS and another called TSQL6 for dd MMM yy.  Is there a standard name for the format dd-MMM-yyyy? I see that dd-MMM-yyyy and dd-MMM-yy show up a lot in PL/SQL but I haven't seen a code or name assigned to them the way T-SQL has numeric codes assigned to all of the convert options for dates for use in the convert function.

Comment: Not AFAIK. Why not call it `DAY_MONTH_YEAR`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dd-mmm-yyyy format is specified in [RFC 5322 "Internet Message Format"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5322/?include_text=1):

> **3.3.  Date and Time Specification**
>
> Date and time values occur in several header fields.  This section
>      specifies the syntax for a full date and time specification.  Though
>      folding white space is permitted throughout the date-time
>      specification, it is RECOMMENDED that a single space be used in each
>      place that FWS appears (whether it is required or optional); some
>      older implementations will not interpret longer sequences of folding
>      white space correctly.
>
> date-time       =   [ day-of-week "," ] date time [CFWS]
>
> day-of-week     =   ([FWS] day-name) / obs-day-of-week
>
> day-name        =   "Mon" / "Tue" / "Wed" / "Thu" /
>                         "Fri" / "Sat" / "Sun"
>
> date            =   day month year
>
> day             =   ([FWS] 1*2DIGIT FWS) / obs-day
>
> month           =   "Jan" / "Feb" / "Mar" / "Apr" /
>                         "May" / "Jun" / "Jul" / "Aug" /
>                         "Sep" / "Oct" / "Nov" / "Dec"
>
> year            =   (FWS 4*DIGIT FWS) / obs-year

So if you really wanted a formal name for it, e.g. for specification documents, you could call it an RFC 5322 date.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think that there is any standard name given to DD-MMM-YYYY format. You may customize or name it as per your convention. For example:- You may customize it to give a name to `DATE_MONTH_YEAR`

I am not sure if that is very much relevant but check this [DateTimeFormatInfo.RFC1123Pattern Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.rfc1123pattern%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)